# What is the best way to test performance of the query Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, performance, benchmarking

I have tested the Rails query with Ruby Benchmark:

```
puts Benchmark.measure { 
  @product_providers = SiteController.fetch_providers(@product_types.keys)
}
```

This is basically the query, to join `product_provider` table with `product_type`, but the logic of query lies outside of the scope of the question.

```
protected

def self.fetch_providers product_types
    fetched_providers = {}
    if product_types && product_types.kind_of?(Array)
        product_types.each do |product_type|
            fetched_providers.merge!( { product_type.underscore => product_type.constantize.joins(:provider) } )
        end
    end
    fetched_providers
end
```

**My question is:**

Why testing the query inside Ruby Bencmark, the result that I get is:

```
0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000796)
```

However when I run query inside of the `rails console` I get results after 4-6 seconds :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use mini profiler to test performance http://miniprofiler.com/
and railscasts on this topic http://railscasts.com/episodes/368-miniprofiler